# ER diagram Relationship among tables

Tags: oracle, entity-relationship

My question is related to the ER-diagram I designed using Oracle SQL developer. I designed this ER-diagram but I don't know how to read the relationships between these tables.

I have created this ER diagram:

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rujfs.png)

As it can be seen that these relations don't look like those normal one to many or many to one relations. Can anyone please help me how to read the relation between SYS.GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS and SYS.INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS? Thanks in advance

Comment: **NEVER** modify the system schemas. You should always create your own user and then create tables in that schema.

Comment: It means that each row  GENERAL_LEDGER_ACCOUNTS can be related to multiple rows in INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS. Also, never use the SYS schema for you objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for identifying my mistake. Highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is described by the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE invoice_line_items
  ADD CONSTRAINT line_item_fk_accounts
  FOREIGN KEY (account_number)
  REFERENCES general_ledger_accounts(account_number);
```

Defines a foreign key with the name `line_item_fk_accounts` on the column `account_number` which references the `account_number` of the `general_ledger_accounts`.

Assuming that it is not`NULL` then this is a many-to-one relationship such that each row of `invoice_line_items` has a relationship to exactly one row in the `general_ledger_accounts` and there can be many `invoice_line_items` for each `general_ledger_accounts`.

---

Similarly, `line_items_fk_invoices` is a many-to-one constraint with many `invoice_line_items` each referencing one row of the `invoices` table.

---

Aside: **NEVER** modify the system schemas. If you do you risk making the database unusable and invalidating any support contract that you have with Oracle. Instead, you should create a user and then work in that schema.

Comment: Thank you for guiding. Now I have make a new user. Help is appreciated.